# How do I emulate holding down left mouse button with the keyboard and mouse library in Python 3x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pycharm, mouse

This is in pycharm in python 3.

Here is my code,

```
import pyautogui, keyboard, mouse
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = 0


while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        pyautogui.moveTo(1990, 200)
    if keyboard.press('k'):
        mouse.press(button='left')
    if keyboard.release('k'):
        mouse.release(button='left')
```

Whenever I try and run it, it just presses the button you pressed on the keyboard, then k twice. I've tried changing `keyboard.press` to `keyboard.KEY_DOWN` and I can't figure out how to use `keyboard.on_press` or `keyboard.on_release` for the life of me.

I'm new to python and reading documentation and I can't seem to be able to figure this out. If anyone knows how to do this properly I would love to know how. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you should use `keyboard.press('k')`, instead of `keyboard.is_pressed('k')`?
https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/README.md

Comment: maybe update your question with what your trying to achieve and your expected outcome

Comment: i  am not sure, that's why I'm asking. and the title has what I am trying to achieve and what my expected outcome is.